# Generalizing Solutions for Trigonometric functions (Secant)

Tags: trigonometry

I have been working on the problem: $3\sec^2(2x)-5=1$
Where you have to solve for x and then enter the generalized solutions in ascending order. This is using the Acrobatiq platform, but I am uncertain how to format the answer.

Thus far I performed the following:

1. $3\sec^2(2x)-5=1$ (+5 both sides)
2. $3\sec^2(2x)=6$
3. $\sec^2(2x)=2$ (Divide 3 both sides)
4. $\sqrt{\sec^2(2x)}=\sqrt2$ (Square both sides)
5. $\sec(2x)=\pm \sqrt 2$

From $\pm \sqrt 2$ I get the points $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{5 \pi}{4}$

Generalizing the solution I get $2x=\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k$ which I then obtain the solution: $\frac{9 \pi}{8}$ .

For $\frac{5 \pi}{4}$ I get $2x=\frac{5 \pi}{4}+2 \pi k$ = $\frac{13 \pi}{8}$

Dividing both solutions by 2 I get: ${\frac{9 \pi}{4}, \frac{13 \pi}{4}}$
(The question is stating that it wants the answer for $2\pi k$ though there are other solutions i.e. $\frac{\pi}{8}$)

When entering these answers for $x$ its incorrect.. am I performing something incorrect? Or is there specific formatting to the Acrobatiq platform? (If anyone is familiar)

Comment: $\frac{5\pi }{4}+2\pi k\:=\:\frac{\left(5\pi +8\pi k\right)}{4}$ unless you already assumed k=1

Comment: Your very first line says, in particular, that $1=6=2$. Are you sure that these three numbers are the same number? Please do yourself a favor and look up somewhere what the "$=$" symbol is called, and why it's called that, and what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Your general sub-solutions were both slightly incorrect, and (2) you'd made arithmetic mistakes. So, the correction is:

$\quad2x=\pm\frac\pi4+2\pi k \implies x=\frac\pi8(8k\pm1) \implies x=\pm\frac\pi8,\pm\frac{7\pi}8,\pm\frac{9\pi}8,\ldots$

$\quad2x=\pm\frac{5\pi}4+2\pi k \implies x=\frac\pi8(8k\pm5) \implies x=\pm\frac{3\pi}8,\pm\frac{5\pi}8,\pm\frac{11\pi}8,\pm\frac{13\pi}8,\ldots$

And notice that the second sub-solution would have been nicer had you started out with the $\sec(2x)$ root that is nearest 0 (i.e., $-\frac{3\pi}4$ instead of $\frac{5\pi}4$). Then it would've been rewritten more simply as $x=\frac\pi8(8k\pm3).$

Also, the two sub-solutions can be combined to give a final general solution $$x=\frac\pi8(2n+1).$$

P.S. Incidentally, it's worth checking out [this thread](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/14531/372), which explains how you're misusing the “=” sign.

Comment: Hi! Shouldn't it be $\frac{-\pi \:}{4}$ for the second case than $\frac{5\pi \:\:}{4}$ ? Or maybe its different country different rule, maybe but I remember being thought to assume theta is between 180 and -180

Comment: Actually for the two cases, you need to write, $x = 2\pi k \pm \theta$. Otherwise, half of the values of $x$ are neglected. For example, $\frac{3\pi}{8},\frac{7\pi}{8}$ are also solutions...

Comment: @Ak. Thanks for the catch. Have edited that into the answer.

Comment: @AdilMohammed Did you mean $-\frac{3\pi}4$ instead of $-\frac{\pi}4$? I meant to stick closely to the OP's own solution and point out only their fatal errors, but have now edited the answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the definition of $\sec$ and congruences to solve it in a simple way:
$$\sec^22x=2\iff \cos^2 2x=\frac12\iff \cos 2x=\pm\frac{\sqrt 2}2.$$
Now

- $\cos 2x=\frac{\sqrt 2}2\iff 2x\equiv \pm\frac\pi 4\pmod{2\pi}\iff x\equiv \pm\frac\pi 8\pmod{\pi}$
- $\cos 2x=-\frac{\sqrt 2}2\iff 2x\equiv \pm\frac{3\pi}4\pmod{2\pi}\iff x\equiv \pm\frac{3\pi}8\pmod{\pi}$.